# Git fetch a bad object from an older repository

Tags: git

So, I recently migrated our git servers and during the migration I think some objects got left off in the old repo. This was a couple of weeks ago and today I tried to run git gc --aggressive  on the repo in the new server but it failed with the below error:

```
error: Could not read a23bacz
fatal: bad tree object a23bacz
error: failed to run repack
```

Then, I went to my old repo and tried to grab that object by following:
[Git: fetch a specific object from a remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083420/git-fetch-a-specific-object-from-a-remote)

i.e. I ran git cat-file tree a23bacz > 3b... and then I copied that object to the repo on my new server. However now, I get the below error:

```
fatal: loose object a23bacz (stored in 
./objects/a2/3bacz) is corrupt
```

I also ran git fsck:

```
git fsck
broken link from  tree 1a4da9z
            to    tree a23bacz
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: "Corrupt loose object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)

Comment: Yeah but there is some things different. I tried follow Linus's suggestion from https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt but for me `git ls-tree 2d9263c6d23595e7cb2a21e5ebbb53655278dff8 ` gives me the folder name rather than filename (my-magic-file). The folder name, I think is the first two letters of commit_hash.